# Safari versus standard animation syntax

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm trying to create a simple animation but getting confused between safari syntax and standard syntax.

Should I use `@-webkit-keyframes` or just `@-keyframes`?

So I created a div and created an animation based on it.

Css:

```
.about4 {background-color: red;-webkit-animation-name: 
aboutanimation; animation-name: aboutanimation; 
animation-duration: 4s;} @-keyframes animationname 
{from {background-color: red;} to {background-color: 
green;}}
```

Html:

```
<div class="about4">About</div>
```

Css lint won't accept my syntax using `@-keframes` which w3 school says works. The animation doesn't work either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's @keyframes not @-keyframes
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes

Answer (score 0):

I used just @keyframe + autoprefixer for different browser:

```
  @keyframes blinker {
    50% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
  }
```

More on auto-prefixer: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-autoprefixer